# Formula to rearrange order

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I specify a value to be looked up in a range and then another

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$A$5,MATCH(1,($A$6:$A$6<=$B$2)*($A$3:$A$5>=$B$2),0)),"")`

It returns a blank cell(A7, expected result 25) for some reason when `A6:A6` equals to a value of `B2` but it finds a greater than equal to when its less, in the second range parameter.

What I need is first search a range and if not found search a second range. Can it be modified to search backward?

B2=22

A3=7

A4=25

A5=45

A6=2

A7=25

Comment: Some sample data and the expected result would make the question easier to answer, thanks!

Comment: I mean search backwards in each search range

Comment: Can you not just use `IfError(IfError(FirstIndexMatch, SecondIndexMatch),"")`?  If you need to take into account blank values, you would want an If-Statement to include `IfError(IfError(If(FirstIndexMatch="",FirstIndexMatch,SecondIndexMatch),SecondIndexMatch),"")`.  Regarding the "search backwards" you would need VBA to do that.

Comment: The LOOKUP function can return results via "search backwards", but it's hard to give an accurate answer without sample data and expected results.

Comment: I was assuming that the first range in my formula was A6:A6 is this incorrect because it seems to search the second range only when A6:A6 is lower than B2 and give blank cell otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

> What I need is first search a range and if not found search a second
>   range.

We need to perform two separate lookups.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP("h",A1:A5,1, FALSE), VLOOKUP("h",B1:B5, 1, FALSE))
```

Following formula attempts to look up `"h"` in array `A1:A5`, if it's not found, it performs `VLOOKUP`on the second array. Obviously, you can replace `"h"` with whatever cell reference you need, but the principle of the formula stays the same.

[image]

Comment: This doesnt work, i get a blank cell anything above first range is higher than B2, or give the highest value lower than B2. It doesnt look on the second range.